# wordpress: how to change in line syles in wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I have a wordpress theme installed on a site:

http://airport-taxis-online.com/

I have one inline style element named .da-slider which I cannot seem to find within the theme.

According the firebug it should be in the  tag within the header area however for the life of me I cannot find this within the theme. I'm most probably being a bit of a WP noob so apologies for that in advance.

I tried looking in wp_header() as that seemed to be the logical place for could not find it and thought maybe I'm looking too deeply for this.

Comment: That class is the slider section of your theme below your header and navigation. `<div class="flexslider da-slider">` The "Airport Taxis Online" bit.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate that.

Comment: If I were you I would delete this question because it's not going to help anyone else who has coding issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've detected that you are using the theme "Firmness" - and if you go to the functions folder and open up the file called firmness-image-sliders.php, you will see this on line 25:

```
<div class="flexslider da-slider" >
```

I hope that helps!

Here's a [Screenshot of the Theme Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3A0e.png)

Comment: Thanks! I found it - much appreciated.